# please help with approval process!

Tags: formula, process-builder, picklist, validation-rule, approval-process

Need help! I am trying to do an approval process, that will be triggered automatically from process builder. The problem I have, is picklists. I want the approval to go out automatically on the condition of specific change in picklist. "Forecast Category" 1,2,3,4,5 . If Opportunity is currently in category 4, users can change is to 5(close won), but if they want to change for 3,2 or 1, record is sent for approval. I tried playing with Validation rules, to prevent users changing, but Validation triggered some other unrelated processes(( and for Process builder and approval process I can not find a way.
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using priorvalue to check what it was before and what it is now?

Something like this should work for the entry criteria where you check if it used to be 4 and if it is now 3,2,1.

```
PRIORVALUE(ISPICKVAL(Forecast_Category__c, "4") && 
(
 ISPICKVAL(Forecast_Category__c, "3") ||
 ISPICKVAL(Forecast_Category__c, "2") ||
 ISPICKVAL(Forecast_Category__c, "1") ||
)
```

Comment: Hi Dan, Thank you! I think I found the way for processes to work with prior value in the Process Builder. Like "Prior Forecast Category" 4, new is not 5))) looks like it's working. I tried your formula for a validation rule (need to make 1 field mandatory if the change is made(comments), but is throws errors. But picklists in formulas, can be tough, still looking for a working validation rule for this. Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: I think we should separate out your question because it's a little confusing bouncing back and forth between criteria for approval process and validations. If you got the process builder issue fixed lets mark this resolved and create a new question for the validation. Make sure you post what you have thus far and what the error you are getting is.

Comment: Thanks Dan! will mark this as complete.